# Global country based raster

Tags: geospatial, images, global

I am looking for a raster in WGS84 where all the countries in the world are available. 
This raster, in principle, should change the resolution of the pixel at the equator or the poles. The resolution should change as the earth is not planar.

What I am trying to do is multiply a raster that I have with 1) all the protected areas in the world, 2) where other protected areas should be. By multiplying these rasters I intend to obtain the area per country.

Comment: why do you want the resolution to change with latitude? could you expand on the question to say what you are trying to do

Comment: I have explained what I aim to do.

Comment: this might not be the best way to go about that, you may want to go back to https://gis.stackexchange.com and ask there about this

Comment: I have asked and they put me a negative mark, this is why I wanted the raster file. I will go back and ask them. Thanks!

Comment: you need to describe what you are trying to do there rather than the data you want.

Comment: Couldn't you generate a raster file from the existing polygonal country data?